# Extract the real video file link from video player in HTML

Tags: url, video, android-mediaplayer, embed

I have scraped a whole website and this website contains many videos links, those links are player in a iframe or embed video player, I want to extract the real file link from this link to be able to play this links in normal videos players like MX player & VLC player.

here's some examples:

```
https://uptostream.com/iframe/b4ds1h0f1bim
https://mega.nz/embed/SvgExbqK!S0hknrLUVQBYfFUcCku4oWksbqQ3QC_7txrNZtAFFKQ
https://www.4shared.com/web/embed/file/xOdD84VBea/
```

actually the links are on multis servers and each server implemented the player in his own way in a web page, so is there any way I can extract the real file link that contains looks like: example.com/video.mp4 to be able to play it in a video player on mobile without using web page/browser?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller PHP Laravel for backend, flutter for mobile apps,
I have tried to scrap the real file link from the embed player but it's mostly protected links, so even if you copy it and try to play it it will not work. 
I've stocked at this point, I need to get the real file link that this web page is playing, https://uptostream.com/iframe/b4ds1h0f1bim or maybe if there is some service that can convert this type of links to a temporary file link that we can play it directly in MX player or EXO player.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice. Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: If this isn't something you are programming, then this question is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: It is also off-topic to ask for recommendations for services.